# Is there is any benefit of using all the cards while in a dungeon?

Tags: guild-of-dungeoneering

In 'Guild of Dungeoneering', while in a dungeon, you get new cards each round and can use max of 3.

If you use all 3, is there any benefit? if you use less is there a down side effect?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get benefits from using all the gold cards, but up to you if you need all the rooms or not -- most of the time you won't use all the rooms (since they're only used to connect places).

Answer (score 2):

There's no bonus for using all 3 cards or penalty for not doing so. It's up to you to place what you need!